# Edit: Can I detect *any key* being pressed without input or installing any module?

Tags: python, text, enter, grok

I am writing a code where the text comes out like this:

```
import time
def animation(phrase):
  for i in phrase:
    print(i,end="",flush=True)     #Animates text to be printed out one by one
    time.sleep(0.035)
  print(phrase)
```

While the text is coming out one by one, the user can press enter in between the letters. After, that I have a code that asks for input and it assumes the *enter key* was the input the user put in.

I have tried using the keyboard module and other modules, I also want to avoid using the input function to detect whether it is an enter key or not.

I want to detect, at any point in my program when the enter key is pressed.

*P.S I am using Grok, on online Python platform.*

Comment: You really should have mentioned that you're using an online Python environment in the actual question, rather than a comment, as it invalidates *all* of the answers you've received.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the question to incorporate this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect keyboard input you will need to use the Curses library.
Which is a built-in library in python.

```py
import curses
import os


def main(win):
    win.nodelay(True)
    key = ""
    win.clear()
    win.addstr("Detected key:") # curses version of print

    while True:
        try:
            key = win.getkey() # here it tries to detect the key
            win.clear()
            win.addstr("Detected key:")
            win.addstr(str(key)) #print the key to the display here
            if key == os.linesep:
                break #check where there is a line seperation if so it breaks
        except Exception:
            # No input
            pass #If no key is pressed it just passes and loops again


curses.wrapper(main)
```

Here is an example where it checks whether a key is pressed and then displays it to the window.

you can edit this to your needs.

Tutorial on Curses Library

- https://www.devdungeon.com/content/curses-programming-python
- https://linuxhint.com/python-curses/
- https://medium.com/explorations-in-python/an-introduction-to-curses-in-python-7686b9641190
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Db4oc8qc9RU

Here is a minimal example in curses

- https://gist.github.com/claymcleod/b670285f334acd56ad1c

Comment: I have read another comment by @jsbueno and is the Curses library non-windows only?

Comment: well, for windows use you may need to install windows-curses https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/

Comment: to install it or any other library. run this command in your terminal
`pip install library-name`

Comment: The software I'm using, Grok, has curses but when I copy and pasted the program, there was just lots of whitespace.

Comment: hmm... that's odd.

Comment: I think it's showing up whitespace because the win.clear() fails to work on my Python software.

Comment: Apart from that, the rest of the code works fine.

Answer (score 3):

While it "is possible" to do so without installing any extra-library, I'd say, it is possible, of course, but it is complicated:

To be able to read keys without waiting from an enter, requires reconfiguring the terminal device(the bridge between the program that displays a terminal window for you and the `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` files the Python code "sees"). This reconfiguration takes a lot of parameters, is different across windows and other operating systems, and you have to restore the default configurations after you are done reading the keyboard: it can be a lot of code.

On the other hand, there are libraries that do all that for you. One such library is "terminedia". It is lightweight, currently with one single dependency - it comes with the `getch()` function that automatically does the configuration/deconfiguration above, and waits for a single key-press in between:

```
from terminedia import getch
import time

def animation(phrase):
  for i in phrase:
    print(i,end="",flush=True)     #Animates text to be printed out one by one
    getch()  # wait for a keypress
  print(phrase)
```

(disclaimer: I am terminedia's author. For other people reaching here in search of non-blocking keyboard reading - there is also `terminedia.inkey`: won't block at all waiting for a keypress, and `terminedia.ainput`: offering an async version of Python input.)

Comment: (i think the currently publsihed termiendia version 0.4.2 is failing on windows -  to use on that system use version 0.3.1 with "pip install terminedia==0.3.1"  .  Curses on the other answer, comes along Python, but it is also non-windows only)

Comment: My Python engine says:Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "program.py", line 1, in <module>
    from terminedia import getch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'terminedia'

Comment: I don't think my Python engine allows me to get the library terminedia.

Comment: termienida is a 3rdy party library which has to be installed.

Comment: I am using Grok Learning, so would it be possible on there? It's a python teaching website.

Comment: @jsbueno It's fantastic lib!

Comment: "I am using Grok Learning": in browser implementations of Python for learning or working (like Jupyter), use another approach, completly different from the terminal and its underlying Input/output stack: **none** of the libraries (or code)  offering to reconfigure the terminal to detect a single key-press **will work**.

Comment: Instead, each implementation of an in-browser Python console have to offer its own way to communicate browser-events to your Python code (and not all will have a way). Jupyter notebooks can do that via its widgets, for example: https://minrk-ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Events.html

Comment: hey @jsbueno your terminedia library is really good. Nice work!